Why wasn’t Adam a hunter gatherer?
We see in Genesis 2:15 that Adam is commended to work the land, thus a farmer. How does that align with the supposed fact that we were hunter gatherers before farmers?
In Genesis 2, we also see that man (Adam) was created before animals. This also doesn’t align with the interpretation that Adam is the first Homo sapiens rather than the first human, which could’ve been a good justification as of to why Adam was directly a farmer.
Many thanks

Humans weren't even permitted to eat meat until Noah.

@shmosel How do we reconciliate this with the hunter gatherers?

Why do they have to be reconciled?

Animals were created before Adam: Genesis 1:24-25. Adam was created in the next verses, Genesis 1:26-27.

2:15 does not necessarily refer to being a farmer -- see the Or Hachaim there https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.15?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=en

The work in the Garden of Eden did not require developing land: the garden produced the food. Adam's work was to develop his soul and to guard it from damage (Sforno on 2:15)

According to the Biblical account, Adam was created some 5,800 years ago, straight into the Agricultural Revolution.
